# Math Competition Problem Algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

I been trying this problem but cannot get anywhere. please help. thank you.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 3):

If I let $\mu=ab+bc+ca$, then $\mu/(abc)=1/2016$, that is $abc=2016\mu$.
Then $a$, $b$, $c$ are zeroes of
$$X^3-2016X^2+\mu X -2016 \mu=(X-2016)(X^2+\mu).$$
Without loss of generality, $a=2016$, $b=-c$, etc.

Comment: Is it 1/2016^2015

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Took the liberty to fix an obvious typo, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I'm not the one who asked the question, but how did you arrive to the cubic equation?

Comment: @Hushus46 Note that $abc$ appears in the relation: $$(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)=x^3-(a+b+c)x^2+(ab+bc+ca)x-abc$$ where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are of course its roots. This is why such a cubic is considered. Given that $abc=2016\mu$, let us require values for $a$, $b$ and $c$ to generate this polynomial. Trivial choices are: $a=2016$, $b=-c$ then we have $-b^2=\mu$. Now, let $b=\sqrt{-\mu}$ and we have $c=\sqrt{-\mu}$. Thus the cubic becomes $$(x-2016)(x-\sqrt{-\mu})(x+\sqrt{-\mu})=(x-2016)(x^2+\mu).$$

Answer (score 2):

Invert the second constraint:
$$
\frac1{\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c}=2016\\
\frac1{\frac{bc+ca+ab}{abc}} = 2016 \\
\frac{abc}{ab+bc+ca}=2016
$$
Subtract that from the first constraint:
$$
(a+b+c)-\frac{abc}{ab+bc+ca}=0 \\
(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)-abc = 0
$$
Notice that when $a=-b$ the left side becomes $(c)(-b^2) - b^2c = 0$ so $(a+b)$ will be a factor of $(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)-abc$.  Similarly, $(b+c)$ and $c+a$ will be factors. In fact, it is easy to check that
$$
(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)-abc = (a+b)(b+c)(c+a)
$$
and since $(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)-abc =0$, at least one of $(a+b), (b+c), (c+a)$ must be zero.  (That is, two of the variables must be negatives of each other.) Without loss of generality, then, we can choose $a=-b$ and then since $a+b+c=2016$, we have $c=2016$.

Finally, the first two terms in the expression we want cancel, and the answer is
$$
\frac1{c^{2015}} = (2016)^{-2015}
$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Factor the numerator of the algebraic expression 
$$\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} - \frac{1}{a+b+c}$$
What can you conclude about the numbers $a$, $b$, $c$?

Comment: Is it 1/2016^2015

Comment: @Derive Foiler: Look at $a$, $b$, $c$ as some variables. You will get a rational expression. The numerator factors nicely.